# Using devDependencies to override dependencies when running locally

Tags: npm

I have packages I want to run using a local version when running the code locally and published versions when running in production. Is there a way to do this with one package.json file using devDependencies? Something like the following, where the `devDependencies` will get used when running locally and the normal `dependencies` will get used when deployed to production:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@me/pack1": "^1.0.1"
    "@me/pack2": "^1.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@me/pack1": "file:path/to/pack1"
    "@me/pack2": "file:path/to/pack2"
}
```

Currently, I am manually installing the local version after pulling a new branch, then reinstalling the deployed version before pushing my local changes. I am looking to remove this process if possible.

Comment: Github issue on this topic: https://github.com/npm/feedback/discussions/775